# How to check PCNTL module exists

Tags: php, requirements, pcntl

I write simple requirements checking script. It checks all required PHP modules installed. I need to check if pcntl is installed. But this module is accessible only in cgi environment and invisible for web queries. extension_loaded('pcntl') and function_exists('pcntl_fork') both return false. How can I perform this check?

Comment: At the end of the day if `function_exists('pcntl_fork') == false` you can't use `pcntl_fork`

Comment: The problem is that if pcntl is present it still invisible until you run script without server, i.e. /usr/local/bin/php script.php. If you run script such method it will work fine. But if you want to check it from web like http://domain.com/req_check.php - there it will be hidden.

Comment: The you are going to have to create a separate  capability fishing script to get the capabilities from the CLI. you should be able to run that one from shell_exec and parse the returned data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called cli_supports.php

```
  <?php
  $supports = array();
  if (function_exists("pcntl_fork")) $supports[] = "pcntl";
  echo implode(",", $supports);
  ?>
```

Then from your feature detection scripts do.

```
  $cli_features = explode(",", shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/php ".escapeshellarg(_DIR_."/cli_supports.php")));
```

Answer (score 19):

Running `php -i | grep pcntl` will return the following if pcntl is enabled.

```
pcntl
```

`pcntl support => enabled`

Answer (score 12):

If it is installed, the code bellow returns `true`

```
var_dump (extension_loaded('pcntl'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's supported (or shared object exists) then check your php.ini and make sure it's loaded as an extension.

`extension_loaded()` should work (and what I prefer over `function_exists()`), and the only reason I can imagine it wouldn't is you not loading the shared object.